# SQL increment index and update column every week

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a table named `the_week` with 2 columns (week, id)
I'm using this SQL script to store to the db.
`UPDATE the_week SET week = 0 WHERE id = '0'`

To share more of my project I'm using wordpress so the usage is more with $wpdb
**Basically, I want to increment the value every Thursday and save it to the db.**

```
  <?php $today = date("l"); ?>

  <?php if ( strtolower($today) == 'thursday' ) { ?>
      <?php $week_index++; ?>
      <?php $wpdb->query( "UPDATE the_week SET week = $week_index WHERE id = '0' " ); ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Now I'm doing something wrong here because this code is running when the user visits the website and of course I don't need it to rely on that.

How can I do that?

Comment: A CRON job looks like what you want

Comment: Just like storing an age, it would be best (IMHO) to store the start date and calculate the week no from that.

Comment: @NigelRen it would be benificial but you have to visit the site every tursday manually if you user not visit the data will not updated that's why cron job is the best option for it it

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan it has nothing to do with visiting the site, the week is calculated by the difference between the current date and the date stored on the record.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use a cron job if you are on live server you can create a cron
> job to hit on every thursday and hit that script which contain the
> code of updating the values

Comment: it is like a robot that hit you query every Thursday

Comment: can you share an example of a cron job? where do I host it or access it?

Comment: https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-configure-a-cron-job/

Comment: ok, but after I create a cron job how do I say run 'this' script that I want?

Comment: in the command box while creating cron job give your url  like this " wget https://www.yoursite.com/script.php " use wget keyword before your url it is mandatory

Comment: my pleasure :) bro

Comment: what if I want a safer way?
if someone knows that URL of the command, that can damage my database.
correct me if I'm mistaken

Comment: bro just pass a secret key  in url like  www.yoururl.com?id=22568985hji and make condition in your script if the code match then execute or you can also check $_SERVER['https_referer']; its shows where the come from so you can check if it contain your server url then proceed accordingly